# Should my first point be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, itineraries

I have multiple visa schengen from Netherlands as per my trip plan was to travel Amsterdam but then due to some changes i have to drop my travel to netherlands. Now if i need to travel to spain on same visa issued by netherlands state, can i travel or apply for spain schengen ?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Officially, your visa is supposed to be issued by the country in which you intend to spend the most time.

But look at all the "related questions" (links on the right).  For example, [Not going to the Schengen country that issued your visa because of genuine reasons](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109881/not-going-to-the-schengen-country-that-issued-your-visa-because-of-genuine-reaso)

Comment: Officially the visa application is supposed to be filed with the country that is the _main destination_ of the visit. Time spent there is one way to argue for a main destination but not the only, and not always the governing way.